# MS Edge changing the attribute's blank value to 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-edge

I've created the code javascript to grab values of the list, but in windows edge, it's return value 1 where the actual value of that `<li>` is blank.
For Ex:
**HTML Code**

```
<ul>
   <li value="">Test 1</li> 
   <li value="a">Test 2</li>
   <li value="b">Test 3</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript/JQuery Code**

```
$('ul').find('li').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('value')); //1st <li> value is showing "1", it should be blank as it is set already
});
```

The code is working fine on all other browsers only it's not working for the Microsoft Edge

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/53sos61u/

Comment: *"Here is the jsfiddle link"* Even better would be an **on-site** Stack Snippet; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I agree with you, it should be data-value. But I've added the code everywhere and the situation is something like I can't change the code, so need some small modification in the javascript. Is there any way?

Comment: I don't think so, no; see my answer for why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why it's important to use the [`data-` prefix](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) for custom attributes.

`value` has [a meaning for `li` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value):

> The `value` attribute, if present, must be a [valid integer](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-integer) giving the [ordinal value](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#ordinal-value) of the list item.

In theory, it's only for `li`s inside `ol`s, but... *(This isn't new; it's [in the HTML4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#adef-value-LI) as well, though characteristically less-thoroughly defined...)*

So you'll have to make the change to `data-value` in order to use it for something else, reliably, cross-browser.